# Can't import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

Tags: gradle, import, annotations, androidx

I can't import `annotation.NonNull` in Android Studio. I have tried all the suggestions mentioned on StackOverflow but still can't resolve the issue (NonNull in Red).

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
```

This is the version of Android Studio that I'm using.

Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023

I have the followings in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'
    implementation files('tmplibs/flutter.jar')
}
```

Also, the followings in gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11
```

This drives me crazy, really don't know what is missing. I invalidate the cache and restart the Studio but that doesn't help. Appreciate any help.

This is a for Flutter Plugin project. I just realized if I open the project from /project root, I have this problem. If I open project from /root project/android, then it is fine.  I don't have `build.gradle` or `settings.gradle` under the project root but they are under `/project root/android`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy `build.graddle` and `settings.graddle` from android directory to project root directory. I also had to delete .idea directory under root project and restart the Android Studio.

This is my first time using Android Studio to create a Flutter plugin and never thought that it could be this difficult.